# Update form field based on another form field

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input, onchange

I have 2 forms that each do specific calculations. On one of the forms (TCO), one of the input fields populates based on a input field in the other form(MORTGAGE).

The script I have below works fine --

```
<script>
    function checkVar()
    {
        if( typeof myglobalvar != 'undefined' && myglobalvar != '' && myglobalvar != 0 && jQuery( '.mclass input' ).length )
        {
            jQuery( '.mclass input' ).val( myglobalvar );
            fbuilderjQuery.fbuilder.calculator.defaultCalc( '#'+jQuery( '.mclass input' ).closest( 'form' ).attr('id') );
        }
        else
        {
            setTimeout( checkVar, 1000 );
        }
    }

    checkVar();
</script>
```

In the first form, I have my equation for my calculations wrapped in another function --

```
(function(){
    myvar = fbuilderjQuery.fbuilder.calculator.format( ROUND((fieldname17*(fieldname23/100)/fieldname12)), { 'groupingsymbol' : ',' } );
    myglobalvar = myvar;
    return myvar;
})()
```

Everything is working fine however when the value in the first form is changed or updated, the second form does not update.

Is there a way to add some kind of event/change listener for whenever the field updates?

EDIT:
using one of the suggestions in the comments below --

```
document.getElementById('fieldname22_7').addEventListener("oninput", function(evt) { 
var Mor = document.getElementById('fieldname22_7').value; 
document.getElementById('fieldname47_20').value = Mor; });
```

But I receive the follow error --

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Am I even close?

Comment: Could you post a jsfiddle with your code to see the problem in live environment?

Comment: I cant because its for a form plugin. The scripts work fine, but I just need the script to slightly be modified to constantly listen for any changes so that it will always update the input field if the values change.

Comment: You can add plugins or any script to jsfiddle if it is hosted. Give me the name of the plugin and I'll make a little jsfiddle and later you could modify it. Without an example is very difficult guide you.

Answer (score 1):

I can't fully understand your code, but I think, it could help you.
So. You have two forms like this:

```
<form>
    <input id="input-1">
</form>
<form>
    <input id="input-2">
</form>
```

And if the value of "input-1" changed, you want the "input-2" to be changed too.

In this case you should use the 'oninput' event.
So add an event handler to "input-1"

```
<input id="input-1" oninput="myEventHandler();">
```

And the event handler is:

```
<script>
function myEventHandler() {
    var in = document.getElementById('input-1').value;
    //Check the input
    document.getElementById('input-2').value = in;
}
</script>
```

I hope it will help you!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, you do seem to understand my problem. However, I do not have the ability to modify the inputs myself, they are generated by a plugin. I am trying to modify my above scripts so they continue to work the same, cause they are currently working fine, I just need it to be able to listen constantly for any updates or changes.

Comment: Okay. But i think the generated forms and its inputs have IDs. And after generation you can add event listener to them:
document.getElementById(input_id).addEventListener("oninput", function(evt) {
   var in = document.getElementById('input-1').value;
    //Check the input
    document.getElementById('input-2').value = in;
}

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle with your files?
If I can see your problem, I can give you help in short time.

Comment: I cant make a jsfiddle because its a plugin involving custom fields. Your previous comment seems to be what I might need. The input fields do have ids, classes, and names assigned to them. On page load they are all populated either with numeric data or "N/A". I need the 2nd input field to always change anytime the 1st input field does. My original code works for the initial page load but if change anything it doesnt.

Comment: Hey were you able to think of anything?

Comment: Well, sorry, but i have no more ideas. I don't know how your plugin works. It's so hard to answer without seeing the problem.

Comment: Yes. If that error occurs there isn't an element with that ID.